# Golang Google Drive Oauth2 Not Returning Refresh Token

Tags: go, google-oauth

I am able to go through the oauth procedure to get a token which I'm able to successfully use to to interact with GDrive. The token has an AccessToken but no RefreshToken. How do I get a RefreshToken?

This is in a web service. Here's the code that initiates the oauth authorization procedure:

```
// Set up a configuration.
oauthconfig := &oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     XXX,
    ClientSecret: XXX,
    RedirectURL:  "https://MYDOMAIN/gdrivecb",
    Scopes:       []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"},
    Endpoint: oauth2.Endpoint{
        AuthURL:  "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        TokenURL: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    },
}
url := oauthconfig.AuthCodeURL(MYSCOPEDATA, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusFound)
```

Here's the relevant code that's called when /gdrivecb is called (oauthconfig is the same as before, code is the `code` URL parameter:

```
token, err = oauthconfig.Exchange(nil, code)
```

That token contains an AccessToken but no RefreshToken. And it works for an hour (the length of Expiry), but then stops working after that.

Comment: When a code is retrieved, ``access_type=offline`` is needed to be included in the URL for retrieving the code. The URL for retrieving the code is ``https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=###&redirect_uri=###I&scope=###&access_type=offline`` The detail information is https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: The AuthCodeURL() function with oauth2.AccessTypeOffline adds 'access_type=offline' to the redirect URL, so that's already happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not with the code, and the code works if you've never gone through the authorization process before. The problem occurs if you go through the authorization process a second time. You are not shown the privileges being asked for, and a refresh token is not sent. You must force the privileges dialog to be shown again. To do so, add `approval_prompt=force` to the redirect URL.